# Given Two-dimensional Gaussian distribution, how to derive the pdf of Z?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(X,Y) \sim N \left(  
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right)$ and $Z = X I \{XY >0\} - X I \{XY <0\} $

Find the distribution of Z.

From the question, I only know that X,Y are independent and X~N(0,1), Y~N(0,1). I think we should derive the cdf of Z for z>0 and z<0 first in order to get the pdf of Z. However, I don't know how to, since Z=X for XY>0 and Z=-X for XY<0, which is really complicate. Somebody help me please!

Comment: Hi Araceli, welcome to MSE. I wrote down the problem statement in [Latex](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)  (as you should here), please check that it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways...

For example : Let $W=I\{X Y \ge 0 \}$. Notice (show) that $P(W=0) = P(W=1)=\frac12$ and (important, and not so trivial) $W$ is independent of $X$.

$$\begin{align}P(Z\le z) &= P(Z \le z \cap W=0) + P(Z \le z \cap W=1) \\
&= P(Z \le z \mid W=0) P(W=0) + P(Z \le z \mid W=1)P(W=1)\\
&= P(X \le z \mid W=0) \frac12 + P(-X \le z \mid W=1)\frac12\\
&= P(X \le z ) \frac12 + P(X \ge -z )\frac12\\
&= \frac12 ( F_X(z )  + (1- F_X(-z))\\
&= F_X(z )
\end{align}$$

That $W$ is independent of $X$ is intuitive by symmetry. A little more formally:
$$P(W=1 | X=x) =\begin{cases}
P(Y\ge 0)=\frac12 & {\rm if \hskip 3mm} x \ge 0\\
P(Y<0)=\frac12 & {\rm if \hskip 3mm} x < 0\\
\end{cases}$$
Hence $P(W | X) = P(W)$ , and $W,X$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks for answering! That's very helpful. However, I'm still a little bit confused about whether W and X are independent. My thought is that whether xy are positive or negative has nothing to do with the distribution of f(x). Do you have a better explanation?

Comment: @Araceli I added a possible explanation